# Why does wine leave so much leftover data?

Tags: wine

When I `apt-get install wine` it was like a few hundred megabyte download, but when I `purge` it it was 21kb...

Then I deleted the .wine folder thinking it was the cause.

I ran `apt-get install win`e again and it was 21kb download...

Comment: Because wine itself is only a meta-package that depends on other packages to bring in the good stuff. You need to remove those packages.

Comment: Will running apt-get autoremove remove all the other packages?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for a software application to require more than just one package, and when you install the main package, it causes a number of dependent packages to be installed as well.

This is the case with wine: the main package called `wine` doesn't even contain any code at all, it simply just has a dependent package called `wine1.6` which in turn depends on a bunch of other packages.

Of these, `wine1.6-amd64` and `wine1.6-i386` are both around 15MB in size, which will account for around 30MB (both are required, as Windows needs to run both 64- and 32-bit Windows applications).

Then there are a bunch of other packages such as multimedia libraries and fonts.  Depending on how many of these you happened to have installed already, it could have been dozens of MB in download.

If you remove the package `wine` alone, you won't be removing wine - you have to remove its dependencies as well.  Luckily you should be able to do that with `apt-get autoremove wine` so that it removes anything that was automatically installed when you installed wine.